# React Native: recup text from .doc file and display it

Tags: react-native

I call an API and I receive a link of a file .doc, I have to display the text of this file, can anyone please offer me an approach ? there is a library for that ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer

Answer (score 0):

use this [react-native-doc-viewer](https://github.com/philipphecht/react-native-doc-viewer)

Comment: better than react-native-file-viwer ??

Comment: yep.more functionality for doc files

Comment: I have to display content of doc file like in <Text>{doc file content}</Text> it is possible ?

Comment: no issue just upvote it if you consider it a answer

Comment: in fact.. I dont want to open my file with ms doc but juste display content text of doc file